# I downloaded flask successfully but "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'"

Tags: python, flask

I am making a program that displays the average number of machines built over a certain number of days. The company gave me some code to work with but it says

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'"

and I am pretty sure I downloaded Flask correctly. I already tried uninstalling Flask and reinstalling it. Does anyone have any idea what this error is caused by and how to fix it?

Here's the directory:
[image: here's the directory]

The 'app' folder:
[image: directory in 'app' folder]

The stuff I imported:
[image: heres the stuff i imported]

Comment: There's no app.py in your directory so what are you trying to import?

Comment: It's not your Flask installation, it's `from app import app` (the error should also show the exact line where the error is raised). You have an `app` module but none of your screenshots show an `app` file or `app` instance/object. It can also be an error with importing the `app` module itself.

Comment: ahh sry im and intern and idk what im trying to import, the code came like this. should i ask my superviser abt this?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: if you got it from internet then you could add link to source code - and then we can see code. First I would check what you have in file `vertex` - maybe it imports `app` so you could see how to do it in your code. And I would check also if you have `app` in file `app/__init__.py`

Answer (score 0):

i got what you are doing.. you do not need to write the folder name for importing files
you can write

```
import queries
```

not
`from app import queries`
no need to use `import app from app`  too